# Worship of Sri Kala Bhairava

Tags: worship, bhairava

1. Which day of the week is dedicated to Kalabhairava?
2. How to observe Kalaashtami, how to do fasting on that day?
3. What are the things that are offered to Kalabhairava, things that are dear to him?
4. What are the activities that would please Kalabhairava? (for example, I have heard feeding black dogs is pleasing to Kalabhairava)
5. What is the correct version of Kalabhairava Ashtakam? (there are minor variations that can be seen in different sources on the internet)

If anyone can provide the answers, it will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Kal Bhairava worship is tricky to be done in one's home .. usually offering of non veg items like egg as well as alcohol are done. I am not sure if normal devotional worship (without the mentioned offerings) can be done or not.

Comment: @Rickross I believe Satvika Bhakti Upasana can be done of Kalabhairava at home by anyone. I am not interested in Tantra and Tantrik way of worship, also I do not have any 'motive' to achieve with the worship.

Comment: Yes that's alright but if Kala Bhairava can be worshipped in that manner or not is something I am not sure of .. Since you seem to follow Rajarshi Nandy's videos you can ask him directly .. he can guide you better. I think he replies to mails if query is a genuine one.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. He seems to receive thousands of emails every day. I thought I might try here first because I would like to know the sources as well.