# What are 108 names of Kaal Bhairava? Can we chant them on synthetic tulsi mala?

Tags: worship, shiva-purana, japa, bhairava, japamala

Can you share how to worship Kaal Bhairava at home?

Comment: Tulasi Mala is for Vaishnava deities .. for Kal Bhairava use either Rudraksha mala or Sphatika (crystal)

Comment: A similar question was already asked -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/56504/4732

Comment: There is no usually hard and fast rule. But tulsi mala is for Vaishnavites. You *may* use them in cases if you have limited options. But please don't use **synthetic** Tulsi mala, even for Vishnu please. Usually, a little food or bhog or even a glass of water), being seated on the top of a mat (not directly on the ground), and chanting the names of any deity works. Kaal Bhairava is an ugra deity. If you feel uneasy, you may revert to 108 names of shiva without any problem.